# c++ Pass data stored in std::vector to c_func(void* data)

Tags: c++, c, stdvector, void

I've got a `std::vector` and I need to get the hash of its contents from libgcrypt.

How do I get the contents of `std::vector<int-type> vec` into `gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_MD5, (void*)&digest, (void*)buffer, vec.size());` where `buffer` is the `data` in `vec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C++11, pass

```
vec.data()
```

for `buffer`.

Reference:  [Vector::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

If not, pass `&(vec.front())`.  The elements of `vec` are guaranteed to be in contiguous storage.

Comment: Thanks, I am thoroughly embarrassed to have not remembered that.

Answer (score 0):

What does the function `gcry_md_hash_buffer()` expect of `buffer`? Is it supposed to be an array of `int`? If yes, you can pass `&vec[0]` or `vec.data()` - `std::vector` guarantees that underlying representation of data is the same as in a C array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::vector::operator[]` (the index operator), and the address-of (`&`) operator:

```
&(buffer[0])
```

The above first gets a reference to the first element of the vector (`buffer[0]`), the takes its address `&(...)`.

Using it in the hashing function,

```
gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_MD5, (void*)&digest, (void*)(&(buffer[0])), vec.size());
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that many of the parentheses are unecessary, though I normally put them to eliminate the risk of ambiguity and possible errors.